# How to use multiple fields in exists query in Java API Elasticsearch-2.4.4?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, exists

From the REST API of the elasticsearch (version 2.4.4), we can use multiple fields in exists query as:

```
{
  "query": {
    "exists": {
      "field": [
        "field1",
        "field2",
        "field3"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But I couldn't find the equivalent Java API for the same. The java class **ExistsQueryBuilder** takes only one field as the constructor. So, isn't there really any Java API for it? So, the only way to do it from Java API is using bool-should of  exists query for each field?

Comment: Where did you see that you can give an array as input to the exists query? Only a single field is supported.

Comment: @Val you can try the above JSON requests. It actually works. Work as an equivalent to bool-should of Exists query.

Comment: Tried on both 5.6.2 and 6.4.0, doesn't work :-)

Comment: Sorry, I missed to mention the version, I am actually working on Elasticsearch 2.4.4. Will edit the question.